# compare date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, isodate

so i have this document in my collection

```
db.person.insertOne( { name: "vincent", age: 40, alarm: {morning:new Date("2018-11-14T10:00:00Z") , night: new Date("2018-11-14T23:00:00Z")}})
```

and i need to check if there is an alarm (morning alarm or night alarm) in the next hour

here is what i ve tried

```
db.person.find( { "alarm.morning": { $lte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60) , $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60)} })
```

any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`moment`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) library for the simple calculation

```
const moment = require('moment')

const startDate = moment().toDate()
const endDate = moment().add(1, 'hours').toDate()

db.person.find({ 
  "$or": [
    { "alarm.morning": { "$lte": endDate , "$gte": startDate }},
    { "alarm.night": { "$lte": endDate , "$gte": startDate }}
  ]
})
```

**In mongoshell**

```
var startDate = new Date().toISOString()

var today = new Date()
today.setHours(today.getHours() + 1)
var endDate = today.toISOString()

db.person.find({ 
  "$or": [
    { "alarm.morning": { "$lte": endDate , "$gte": startDate }},
    { "alarm.night": { "$lte": endDate , "$gte": startDate }}
  ]
})
```

Comment: thank you for your solution but i working on mongo cmd ! i guess it won't work! any other suggestion please